# Search a value in CSV

Tags: perl, unix

I have csv file, and a value. I want to search is this value is there in CSV or not. Could you please help and tell which code can be used to open CSV file and then find
whether value is available in CSV or not

Comment: Basic open and search calls or a module like `Text::CSV` should be a good start.

Comment: Text::CSV is highly recommended. I always end up there eventually when working with CSV files.

Comment: I have a older version of perl, so can not use Text::CSV, could you please suggest some thing else, maybe how to use grep here

Comment: There's no problem with an older version (unless you're stuck before the .com bubble and are running Perl 4). If it's not installed on your system because it does not ship with Perl, you need to install it from CPAN.

Comment: I strongly suggest go through some basic perl stuff ,and then start programming.http://www.tizag.com/perlT/

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -lne 'if(/"your_value"/){print;exit}' your_csv_file
```

why dont you simply use grep one the command line for this like:

```
grep 'your_value' your_csv_file
```

Comment: +1: You solution is way more elegant than mine.

Comment: $csvnode = grep "US" $filename; giving error:Scalar found where operator expected at new1.pl line 15, near ""US" $filename"

Comment: is this error related to this answer?

Comment: yes, i used  grep "US" $filename but got error

Comment: @Richa : The `grep` command shown is to be run from command line. If you want to use it inside a Perl script the way you've shown, it should be surrounded by backticks `\``

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. the "grep" solution given by @sarathi does not use any perl stuff. its a simple bash command. But you trying to use in perl context which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you can put your value in a  regex, I think this should work:

```
perl -p -e 'unless (m/,valueToSearchAsRegex,/) {$_=""}' filename
```

It will print all lines in the file *filename* having the value.

Else, if you want to do it within a perl program using Text::CSV, you could try:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
open my $io, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";
my $found = 0;
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($io)) {
    my @fields = @$row;
    for my $field (@fields) {
        if ($field =~ m/valueToSearchAsRegex/) {
            $found = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error:Unquoted string "test" may clash with future reserved word at new2.pl line 9.
Bareword found where operator expected at new2.pl line 9, near "'unless (m/,US,/) {$_=""}' test"
        (Missing operator before test?)

Comment: Cant we use grep for this to find a value in CSV

Answer (score 1):

If you can install a CPAN module, try this one: [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aCSV), and you can handle your file like a relational database, querying by SQL interface via DBI.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $value = 'val6';
my @array = <DATA>;

foreach my $a (@array)
{
    my @array2 = split (/,/, $a);
    foreach my $b (@array2)
    {
        if ( $b eq $value )
        {
            print "Given Value is available in hte CSV\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
val1,val2,val3,val4
val5,val6,val7,val7
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Given Value is available in hte CSV
```

Just make sure not read the csv into an array if your csv file is huge. Use file handle with while loop instead.

Here is another shot with `grep`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $value = 'val5';
my @array = <DATA>;

my $out = grep { /$value/ } @array;
if ($out)
{
    print "Given value is present in the CSV\n";
}
else
{
    print "Given value is not present in the CSV\n";
}


__DATA__
val1,val2,val3,val4
val5,val6,val7,val7
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Given value is present in the CSV
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use below code;:my $filename = "/home/a525457/test.txt";

$curr = ('US');
open(my $Filehandle, '<', $filename ) or die $!;


$csvnode = grep "US" $filename;

$foundCSV = 1 if ($curr eq $csvnode);

   print "Create filter";
but getting errorScalar found where operator expected at new1.pl line 15, near ""US" $filename"
        (Missing operator before  $filename?)

Comment: @Richa, please use code blocks to highlight the code. It's unreadable at the moment.

Comment: hey when using above code getting error:Unquoted string "test" may clash with future reserved word

Comment: this ran but not giving expected result