# search some text in csv file

Tags: perl, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search a value in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474483/search-a-value-in-csv)

I have created a perl script.
Lets suppose I want to seach "abc" in a CSV file which contains äbcd. the script that I have written shows me abcd as a output which actually I dont want, could anyone help on this.

Comment: Please add a minimum working example which illustrates your actual state. That make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: what happened to your other question which is the same one?did nt you find any useful answer from it?

Comment: well,pls try to accept the answer if it has worked for you.

Comment: Is that a smudge on my screen or did you write `äbcd` instead of `abcd`? I.e. its not an A but a lower case Ä?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is searching for an ANSI string in unicode file.  I think you can best answer your question by reviewing this regex tutorial that points out an example similar to yours.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: #!/usr/local/bin/perl

use FileHandle;
use warnings;
my $curr;

use lib '/home/a525457';
my $filename = "/home/a525457/test.csv";


my @nodes;
$curr = "L";
open(my $FileHandle, '<', $filename ) or die $!;
chomp($curr);
chomp($filename);
while (my $line = <$FileHandle>)
{
print "lines new: $line \n";
  next if $line =~ m/^#/; # Look at each line and if if isn't a comment
  push (@nodes, $line);   # we will add it to the array.
}


print "$curr";
if (grep /$curr/, @nodes)
{
   print "Create filter";



}
else
{
print "do nothing";
}
close $FileHandle;

Comment: Please see the code above, i used the code given by slayedbylucifer

Comment: this code has little to do with your question

Comment: HI Sarathi, it worked for array but if I try to find something in excel, it doesnt work properly(grep "\b$U\b", "test.csv")
if test.csv contains US, it will pick that up even if i try to find U.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to match exact word in perl:

use the below regex in perl:

```
(/\b"your_word"\b/
```

tested:

**without \b**

```
> echo 'abcd'|perl -lne 'if(/abc/){print}'
abcd
```

**with \b**

```
> echo 'abcd' | perl -lne 'if(/\babc\b/){print}'
> 
> echo 'abc' | perl -lne 'if(/\babc\b/){print}'
abc
```

by looking at your code you are doing this:

```
(grep /$curr/, @nodes)
```

so changing it to :
`(grep /\b$curr\b/, @nodes)`  should work

Comment: The OP is trying to match `"ä"` with `"a"`. You're not answering the question.

Comment: Zaid..are you sure?is that the reason why you have downvoted? But the OP said it worked..

Comment: Not sure why the OP put an umlaut in their example.. I had to re-read the question a few times to understand what they're after